# Value of an attribute can't be updated within beforeInsert()

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I've a **Grails 2.2.1** project having a domain named 'Question'. Within this domain, **beforeinsert()** currently look like this:

```java
def beforeInsert() {
    dateCreated = new Date()
    dateModified = new Date()
}
```

I want to update **dateCreated** if this value is passed from a controller and if not, allow as it is. Here's my modification, but unfortunately its not working:

```java
def beforeInsert() {
    dateCreated = dateCreated ? dateCreated : new Date()
    println dateCreated
    dateModified = new Date()
}
```

Even though println prints updated dateCreated value, when data inserted to database, dateCreated field gets the value of current timestamp every time. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Post the `mappings` portion of your domain.

Comment: Haven't mapped anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `dateCreated` is being automatically set for you is because of the default behavior of `autoTimestamp`. By default, when a property `dateCreated` exists on a domain class Grails will set this value for you.

You can disable this default behavior as such:

```
class Book {
    …
    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp false
    }
}
```

You may want to check out the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can set autoTimestamp value based on condition? Like, I want autoTimestamp to be false only when I manually provide dateCreated value

Comment: Have you tried using your `beforeInsert` code along with disabling `autoTimestamp`? That should accomplish what you want.